# How to stop a command in the Visual Studio Code terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been stopping commands with the trash can for too long. Command period doesn't work on Mac. I can't find anywhere how to stop the terminal via a command. What is it?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can terminate with the Trash icon like you do,
or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. That's the shortcut from the default Terminal application and it also works in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: thats crazy. i had done command C in the past, and totally missed that it was control lol

Comment: Cmd + c is obvious, but it doesn't work. Nothing happens. I am using karabiner app, so... maybe this is the reason?..

Comment: @JohnSmith same with me. did you find any solution?

Comment: @MehulParmar, unfortunately, no. Just close/open the whole terminal.

Comment: Is that simple?! thanks alot   best way to stop running code in terminal

Comment: This only worked for me after disabling key chords in the terminal. You can find this setting by pressing Ctrl+Shift+P, then search for "Preferences: open user settings", and look under User >> Features >> Terminal and uncheck the mark under "Terminal > Integrated: Allow Chords"

Comment: Wrong on both fronts. The trash can icon does not kill the running process. It just makes that terminal window go away inside VS Code. The process will continue to run in the background. Also by default, the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+C in the VS Code terminal is just "copy".

Comment: @JohnSmith I found this key mapping for karabiner that does the trick, I still needed to do a simple mapping of left ctrl + c => left cmd + c, but now my right ctrl + c (and other combos) works as expected.

https://github.com/rux616/karabiner-windows-mode

Answer (score 12):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> works in the terminal, but it didn't work for me in Visual Studio Code. However, hitting <kbd>Q</kbd> did (when running a `git diff` for example).

Comment: this is so strange but it works

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. You are just describing how `git diff` processes the Q key. The question is not about `git diff`, it's about VSCode.

Answer (score 5):

In certain cases, such as running a Node.js server, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> wouldn't work. Instead, you can stop the app or command by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> (i.e., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> for Mac users).

Sample JavaScript code to demonstrate this:

```js
const http = require('http');

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.write('Hello, World!!');
    res.end();
}).listen(5000, () => console.log('Server running...'));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Linux, open the shortcuts:

[image]

Then type kill, and this option will appear.

Double-click on the record, choose a shortcut for it, open the terminal, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>, and press the shortcut you chose.

[image]

The difference in pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> again to close, is that it will not keep the terminal process, but only close it.

Comment: This is a shortcut for using the "Trash Can" to terminate the terminal session. The original poster is seeking to restore the default CTRL+C functionality, which halts the ongoing process without closing the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Neither <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> nor the trash icon actually stopped the server for me.

If you are using the *Live Server* extension by Ritwick Day, there should be a label on the bar at the bottom for the status of the server.

If it reads `Port: 5500` it means it's running. Just click on it to stop it.

[Stop live server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDuAY.png)

The same label now should say *Go Live*. Click on it in order to do exactly that.

[Start live server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpMw1.png)

Comment: Works for this particular extension only.

Answer (score 1):

Many Mac users (including me) get confused with the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys. But <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> should work fine.

Comment: Control + C  in mac OC

Comment: The original poster explicitly mentioned that CTRL+C is not working in the integrated Visual Studio Code terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> clears out the terminal and cancels everything.

Comment: Didn't help. It prints ^[ and that's all.

Comment: Clearing the terminal is different from stopping a process

Answer (score 0):

If it is ':' you see, then <kbd>Q</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

For example: `git config --list` (this will take you to the colon(':') and you may not be able to escape this)

Comment: The original poster is  seeking a solution specific to Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio (2022) the shortcut may actually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: The original poster i seeking a solution specific to Visual Studio Code - Visual Studio 2022 is a different product.

Answer (score -1):

In Visual Studio Code, first hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

It will ask the following question;

*Terminate batch job (Y/N)?*

Press <kbd>Y</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

After this, run the following command on the prompt:

```
exit + <Enter>
```

It will stop the instance.

Comment: The original poster explicitly mentioned that CTRL+C is not working in the integrated Visual Studio Code terminal.

Answer (score -1):

You can kind of bypass the issue by writing
**system("pause")** at the very end of your main function. That works for me like a charm...

Answer (score -1):

You can stop any running command by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> on your keyboard.

Comment: The original poster explicitly mentioned that CTRL+C is not working in the integrated Visual Studio Code terminal.

Answer (score -1):

POSIX signals should work - `ctrl+c` (`SIGINT`) usually works, but occasionally I find I need something more powerful - `ctrl+\` (`SIGQUIT` - "terminate the application dumping core") usually does it.

`SIGKILL` is even more brutal, and generally not advisable as it can cause system instability, and there is not usually a shortcut set up for that in most shells.

Comment: The original poster did not specify a solution exclusive to Linux and clearly stated that CTRL+C is ineffective.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the "kill terminal button"
[image: killbutton]

Comment: The original poster is seeking an alternative solution to the "Trash Can" method, which refers to the "kill terminal button" you've mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

For Mac use this: **Cmd + Shift + C**