# Ctrl-C doesn't break in terminal on Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using the VSCode 1.38.0 on macOS 10.14.6 and running into this problem here:

1. Open a terminal application in the integrated terminal
2. Press Ctrl-C with the focus inside the terminal, while the application is running
3. The terminal does not get a signal to stop the process; instead I can see that it is triggers Mac's copy command (which is normally cmd+c)

I tested this by removing all extensions and resetting all mapped keys, but still get this same issue.

My problem is very similar to this issue linked below, reported by another user, except that I am running a newer version of VSCode on macOS.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/29773

Comment: This happens to me sometimes on OSX and macOS. Ctrl-C works fine for a few days, then suddenly stops working in one terminal tab. I have to close the tab & open a new one.

Comment: The fix for me was resetting "trap" following this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1319732/538233

Answer (score 22):

I solved the problem by using `command .`

You can also use: `control^ c`

Comment: This increase the size of fonts

Comment: @Blazej SLEBODA I have tried it again just now and it is working fine

Comment: So maybe, it depends on a keyboard layout. I use AZERTY on Apple compact keyboard.

Answer (score 8):

On macOS Catalina, <kbd>CTRL+Z</kbd> works for me.

Comment: This will suspend the process and put it in the background. It will return control of the prompt to the user, but the process is still running. You would then need to note the process id and issue a kill command to completely stop the process. (i.e. `kill <id>`) Alternatively, you can issue the `fg` command to resume the process in the foreground.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are still hitting this issue with more recent versions, but for others getting here, you could try a manual keybinding to send the control sequence to the terminal as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52735954/10682164). I changed it to just "ctrl+c" and it works for me, with "Allow Chords" enabled for the Terminal settings and making sure I have no other chords that start with "ctrl+c" since that would intercept the sequence.

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+c",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {
      "text": "\u0003"
    },
    "when": "terminalFocus"
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

With vscode v1.60 you should be able to use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to kill the process (same as <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).

See [Add terminal keybinding for cmd+. -> ctrl+c to match Terminal.app](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/130990)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a MAC, and if you are using an External Keyboard and have reverted settings for Ctrl and Command button, then  <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> should be equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for break in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this can be buggy, but Ctrl-Alt-M (Ctrl-Option-M on a mac) will stop the current batch job when running things like a node Server.

For testing purposes you could write a peice of code that never finishes (like a for loop that won't terminate) and try "ctrl-c" and "ctrl-opt-m" and see what happens. If the problem persists, I would restart the computer and/or make sure Visual Studio and your OS are up to date.

Referenced from this thread: [how to stop a command in the VS Code terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45711242/how-to-stop-a-command-in-the-vs-code-terminal)

Comment: Thank you for chiming in, I tried these steps but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, however the problem still persists.

On Mac OSX Mojave 10.14, the only ***'workaround'*** I found for this issue was:

1. Uninstalling VScode v1.8X*
2. Installing VScode 1.77 (from https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_77)
3. Disable automatic updates on VScode

**don't forget to backup your keyboard settings JSON (or any other custom config that could be lost in this proccess)*

As I said, it's just a workaround, but given that VScode will stop supporting Mojave after v1.85, and I cannot upgrade to a later OSX, it's fine by me.