# How to stop a command in the Visual Studio Code terminal while visual studio isn't in focus

Tags: visual-studio-code

Similar to: [How to stop a command in the Visual Studio Code terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45711242/how-to-stop-a-command-in-the-visual-studio-code-terminal)

Is there a way to stop and/or pause a command when VS Code is in the background or minimised?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows your could use the task manager to kill the node process running your app.
You should see the node task under the if you click to expand the VSC icon